# How to return the last three dates associated with a primary key, inner joined with another table and identify what percentage clicked

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I need to join with two dates.

> Table 1 = TStudy (people were invited)
>
> Table 2 = TClicks (people that clicked)

Each table is associated with a date.

> Table 1 = dInvite (the date that people were invited)
>
> Table 2 = dLogDate (the date that people clicked on the invite)

Both tables have a primary key (lPeopleID) that will allow for a join.

What I want for separate columns:

> - I want to get the last 3 invite dates.
> - I want to get out of the last 3 invite dates, what percentage (or number(s) i.e. 1/3, 2/3, or 3/3 invites) clicked.

Essentially this is a response factor to see how many people that were invited to a study have clicked on the study. There are about 100,000 IDs so I want to be able to show this for each individual ID.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would be a big help.

Comment: Maybe take a peek here. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by transposing the invites and clicks. Then performing a comparison of the dates. Here's how to transpose using CTEs and PIVOT in SQL Server:

```
WITH cteTStudy AS (
        SELECT lPeopleID,dInvite,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lPeopleID ORDER BY dInvite) AS InviteNumber
        FROM TStudy 
    ), cteTClicks AS (
        SELECT lPeopleID,dLogDate ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lPeopleID ORDER BY dLogDate ) AS ClickNumber
        FROM TClicks  
    ), cteTStudyPvt AS (

        SELECT lPeopleID,[1] AS Invite1, [2] AS Invite2, [3] AS Invite3 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT lPeopleID,dInvite,InviteNumber
            FROM cteTStudy
        ) AS SourceTable  
        PIVOT  
        ( 
            MAX(dInvite)  FOR InviteNumber IN ([1], [2], [3])  
        ) AS PivotTable

    ), cteTClicksPvt AS (

        SELECT lPeopleID,[1] AS Click1, [2] AS Click2, [3] AS Click3 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT lPeopleID,dLogDate,ClickNumber
            FROM cteTClicks
        ) AS SourceTable  
        PIVOT  
        ( 
            MAX(dLogDate)  FOR ClickNumber IN ([1], [2], [3])  
        ) AS PivotTable
    )

    SELECT i.lPeopleID,Invite1,Invite2,Invite3,Click1,Click2,Click3,p.lremoved
    FROM cteTStudyPvt AS i LEFT JOIN cteTClicksPvt as c ON i.lPeopleID = c.lPeopleID LEFT JOIN TProfile p ON i.lPeopleID = p.lPeopleID
```

Then write code to compare Invite1 to Click1 etc.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to include lPeopleID as active members and not just everyone in the system. How do we inner join a third table with this to only look at active ID's and not inactive ID's? So the additional table is Table 3 = TProfile. How to determine if they are active is in one of the columns in table 3 which is lremoved = 0 or 1 (0 = no, 1  = yes).

Comment: See my edit added : LEFT JOIN TProfile p ON i.lPeopleID = p.lPeopleID to the last line